# Function to count paths of a given length in a multigraph that do not include backtracking

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I'm trying to write a function to count a specific type of path in a multigraph (so my graph might have multiple edges between the same two vertices). I need to count paths of a given length `n`, between two given vertices `v, w` that do not include backtracking. What I mean by the last condition is that if a particular edge has been traversed from a vertex `v0` to a vertex `w0`, then I do not want to include that edge going from `w0` to `v0` at any point in the same path.

I think this should be a relatively simple modification of a DFS, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to incorporate the fixed length, the backtracking condition, and the global count.

I've tried using a recursive algorithm, but I haven't been able to get everything working simultaneously.

Comment: Always read tag descriptions before dropping the tag onto a question.  This is not a 'graph" question.

Comment: Please share your attempt for a better context

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's settle on a representation.  We need something that can encode:

```
by starting node
    by ending node
        count of edges
```

This can stored in Python by a dictionary of dictionaries of integers that has the symmetry where `multigraph[x][y] == multigraph[y][x]` for all `x, y`.  And we can skip out on the ending node if the count of integers is missing.  So, for example, if `a, b, c, d` are the vertices, the following represents a valid multigraph.

```
{
    a: {b: 3, c: 2, d: 3},
    b: {a: 3, c: 2, d: 1},
    c: {a: 2, b: 2},
    d: {a: 3, b: 1},
}
```

In this graph, note that there are many long paths from `a` to `a` meeting the condition.  That's because there are many potential loops of length 2 and 3, and once a given loop has been traversed once in a direction, it can be traversed that direction any number of times without violating the condition. So we can swap back and forth between similar loops over and over again. So the number of paths grows exponentially with the length.

Note that @ravenspoint's answer is based on Dijkstra's algorithm.  Which won't find paths that revisit the same node many times.  It therefore cannot handle this graph.

Let's start with a small graph and brute force.  If `multi` is a multigraph, and `v` a vertex, then here is a function that lists the edges.

```
def edges (multi, v):
    for w, c in multi[v].items():
        for i in range(c):
            yield (w, i)
```

If the length of the path `n` is very small, it makes sense to just do a brute force enumeration of all paths.  Something like this.  (Your original DFS idea.)

```
def count_paths (multi, n, start, target, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = {}

    if n == 0:
        if start == target:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        answer = 0
        for v, i in edges(multi, start):
            if (v, start, i) not in seen:
                if (start, v, i) in seen:
                    seen.add((start, v, i))
                    answer += count_paths(multi, v, target, seen)
                    seen.pop((start, v, i))
                else:
                    answer += count_paths(multi, v, target, seen)
        return answer
```

But...what if `n` is large?

The outline of a better algorithm is to try each orientation of the edges. Namely fill in `seen` such that for every possible `v`, `w` and `i` that could appear in `seen` exactly one of `(v, w, i)` or `(w, v, i)` appears in `seen`.  And then use dynamic programming to find all of the paths.  (If you're familiar with transition matrices, you can raise the right transition matrix to the right power for large `n`.  This approach is only likely to be appropriate for some programming competitions though.)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is a modified Dijkstra

- Apply Dijkstra to find cheapest path
- Add to output if length = required
- Increment cost of links in path
- Repeat until no new path found, stopping when length is exceeded

---

Here is a screenshot of a run using the sample graph in the @btilly answer

[image]

Comment: I am positive that this does not work.  The problem is sufficiently close to the Hamiltonian Path problem that I would bet it is NP complete.

Comment: I found a graph where your algorithm as stated can cycle between 3 paths, and fail to find paths that follow a mixture of those three. That one is fixable. But there are graphs with paths meeting the stated condition that go around loops multiple times with no backtracking. I found no variation on your algorithm that can find those.

Comment: The looping problem should be easy to reproduce almost immediately. But I posted an answer which includes an example of a multigraph that your algorithm doesn't handle.  Then I outlined several solutions to the problem.  All of which experience exponential slowdowns if the multigraph and path are both long.

Comment: @btilly "an example of a multigraph that your algorithm doesn't handle." Have you actually run my algorithm?  I have added a screenshot of a successful run using your example multigraph.

Comment: And how many paths are there meeting the condition of length, say, 27? Your algorithm found none. It can't, because no path of length 27 can have minimal length. Also your screenshot shows another bug in your implementation. The condition allows you to traverse different edges in different directions. So, for example, there are 6 possible ways to have a length 2 cycle from `a` to `b` and back.  (3 choices of edge out, 2 choices back.)

Comment: What are you talking about?  There can be no paths of length 27 because there are only 4 vertices.

Comment: Authors vary on whether a path can repeat vertices. The condition makes no sense unless you can, so we should allow repeated vertices.  And that lets you have a path that is longer than your set of vertices.